# Exception: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name

Tags: java, spring

The below register.jsp is my user registration page and want to store user details to db using hibernate but when register.jsp file runs its keep showing an exception. and I have mapped the form action in controller.

register.jsp file is:
                In this file user details and I given action "reg" which is mapped in EmployeeController.

Register.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="reg.html">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

EmployeeController.java

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
 @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
        @RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("command") UserBean userBean, 
            BindingResult result) {
        User user = prepareModelUser(userBean);
        userService.addUser(user);
        return new ModelAndView("RegistrationSuccess.html");
    }
}
```

From register.jsp I am trying to call saveUser method which is in EmployeeController.java but whenever I am running register.jsp I am getting an exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute.
```

I tried with commandName and action in the form and in the controller I have mapped based on that. even though, it gives same exception like above. so how I want to configure the controller to submit this register.jsp form. is I required to add configure the controller explicit or what.. And in EmployeeController.java I have an another form controller with same default "command" form submit. that works fine. but here in this I have the possibilities what I searched. but does not works.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803295/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-index-available-as?rq=1

Comment: I have tried what u said in that link. ie) i added commanName="reg" and in the controller i put @ModelAttribute("reg") but still i am getting exception ie) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'reg' available as request attribute. why it is so... same like an another form is working ie) as default, without commandName and with the ModelAttribute("command") in controller. can u resolve it..

Comment: Thank u very much.. i got clear the error..

Answer (score 0):

you are missing commandName in the form tag and also you are doing wrong in your server side method do it like the following

In form

```
<form:form method="POST" action="reg.html" commandName="userBean" modelAttribute="userBean"  >
```

and in server side have it like

```
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute("userBean") UserBean userBean
```